# Git pull fails to parse syntax

Tags: git

When I run this command:

> "Z:/Program Files (x86)/git/bin/git.exe" --work-tree="/www/test/"
>   --git-dir="Z:/www/test/.git" pull

The output is:

> fatal: Could not switch to 'Z:/Program Files (x86)/git/www/test': No
>   such file or directory

What's going on?

Here's what I also tried:

> Z:\Users\Me>"Z:/Program Files (x86)/git/bin/git.exe"
>   --work-tree="Z:/www/test/" --git-dir="Z:/www/test/.git" pull
>
> fatal: Z:\Program Files (x86)\git/libexec/git-core/git-pull cannot be used
>   without a working tree.

I should also add that it works great if I use local command such as `status`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there's a bug in Git and I instead ended up doing `cd /www/test && git pull`.