# git pull with "--work-tree" flag fails

Tags: git, git-pull

I'm running (in a script - trying to avoid using cd):

```
git --git-dir=/test/.git --work-tree=/test/ pull
```

And getting:

```
fatal: /usr/lib/git-core/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.
```

Note that I've run other commands with exactly this structure that have worked (in particular, add, commit, and pull), so I think it's just a pull problem.

A similar problem is documented here: [Git pull fails to parse syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851967/git-pull-fails-to-parse-syntax), but it's not quite the same - they get a different error (and they're running on Windows, so who knows... I'm on Ubuntu).

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory

Comment: Oh, good find. I didn't come across that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to isbadawi for this answer.

Turns out this question has been answered before: [git pull while not in a git directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory).

In a nutshell, this is a bug with git pull. However, since pull is basically an alias for fetching and merging, the following is equivalent to pull (copied from the above link):

```
cd /X
git --git-dir=/X/Y/.git fetch
git --git-dir=/X/Y/.git --work-tree=/X/Y merge origin/master
```