# Git pull fails on a worktree: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)

Tags: git

There is a Git repository `proj.git`, cloned to `proj1` and `proj2`. `proj1` has no worktree, `proj2` has a worktree.

The goal: update `a.txt` in `proj1`, get the change updated to worktree in `proj2`.

The problem: `git pull` fails on `proj2` with an error message:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

**Reproducing the problem:**

Create `proj.git` and `proj1`:

```
$ git init --bare proj.git
$ git clone proj.git proj1
$ cd proj1
- edit a.txt: v1
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "v1"
$ git push -u origin master
```

Create `proj2` with worktree:

```
 $ cd ..
 $ git clone -n proj.git proj2
 $ mkdir proj2_worktree
 $ cd proj2
 - edit .git/config:
   [core]
       ...
       worktree = /path/to/workarea/proj2_worktree
 $ git checkout
```

`proj2_worktree` contains `a.txt`, works as expected.

Check the status of origin in `proj2`:

```
 $ git remote show origin
 * remote origin
   Fetch URL: /path/to/workarea/proj.git
   Push  URL: /path/to/workarea/proj.git
   HEAD branch: master
   Remote branch:
     master tracked
   Local branch configured for 'git pull':
     master merges with remote master
   Local ref configured for 'git push':
     master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Try to pull-in changes in `proj2` (that **does** have `.git`):

```
 $ git pull
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

 $ git init
 Reinitialized existing Git repository in /path/to/workarea/proj2/.git/

 $ git pull
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
 fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

What am I doing wrong? My Git versions are 1.7.10.4 on Debian / 2.1.1 on Cygwin.

**EDIT:**

An additional finding: In `proj2`, the usual `fetch`/`merge` will work as a workaround to the problem:

```
$ git fetch
$ git merge origin master
```

BUT: still, why does `pull` not work?

Comment: Why do u use --bare? bare means no working directory

Comment: `proj.git` is a central repository. Typically, those repositories are kept bare.

Comment: Where are you when you execute `git pull` for proj2? In `/path/to/workarea/proj2`, or in `/path/to/workarea/proj2_worktree`? Does it work if you use `git --git-dir /path/to/workarea/proj2 pull`?

Comment: @poke: `git pull` in `proj2` does not work, but `git --git-dir /path/to/workarea/proj2/.git pull` in `proj2_worktree` works ok. Notice that `git fetch` works in `proj2`, it is only `pull` that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `core.worktree` in `.git/config` is usually a bad idea since it will cause a lot of confusion unless you know exactly what’s going on.

If your plan is to deploy a revision of the repository at `/path/to/workarea/proj2_worktree` without having a `.git` folder inside (which makes sense for deployments), then I’d suggest you to use a more explicit checkout, directly from the bare repository:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/proj.git --worktree=/path/to/worktree checkout master
```

(or execute the command from within `proj.git`, so you don’t need to specify `--git-dir`)

---

As for your actual problem, this might be a bug with an earlier version of Git. I’ve found [some other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080877/git-pull-with-work-tree-flag-fails) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083224/git-pull-while-not-in-a-git-directory) that refer to this, so if my suggestion above does not fit your need, I’d advise you to update your Git version. After all, 1.7.10.4 is almost *three years* old.

Comment: Thanks! This is a deployment, but I need to be able to push updates from the deployment directory to the central repository, so I need to have a non-bare repository in-between? What comes to your latter proposal, the behaviour is the same in Git v.2.3.0. I would be curious to know, what is the correct method for setting up the worktree, if editing `core.worktree` is a bad idea. There is very little documentation on the topic. However, I guess `fetch`/`merge` will do just fine.